# org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

getting the type mismatch exception.
My project is spring and hibernate integration and i am getting error as

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.ProjectDetails]
```

sdnext-servlet.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com" />



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>  
<mvc:annotation-driven /> 
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/**" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/scripts/**" location="/scripts/**" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/**" cache-period="31556926"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/**/resources/**,classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/**" cache-period="31556926"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="defaultController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController">
  <property name="viewName" value="default" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ProjectManagementTool2" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" id="sessionFactory">  
< property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  
< property name="packagesToscan">  
 < list>     
   < value> com.hibernatemappingfile< /value>
  < /list>  
< /property>  
<  property name="hibernateProperties">  
 < props>  
 < prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
  < prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  
   < prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>      
  </props>  
 </property>  
< /bean>  

  < bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" id="hibernateTransactionManager">  
 < property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>  
  < /bean> 


    < bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      < property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
     < property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     < property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>


<  /beans>
```

Why i am getting this error I have seen all the fields are excatly mapped into that bean.Still i am getting that error.

Comment: The exception says `Cannot find class [com.vrnda.hibernatemappingfile.ProjectDetails]` and in your `packagesToScan` the package name says `com.hibernatemappingfile`. Could there be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Hibernate 3 or Hibernate 4? If 3, then is it an old project and you have to use 3? This is my configuration for 4 and it works :

```
 <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.journaldev.spring.model"/>
```

The value above just gives the path to the package where all Model files are. Rest is handled by Spring. Try this out, and check why are you using Hibernate 3.

Comment: `packagesToScan` can be used with Hibernate 3 with `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: I know it can be used with Hibernate 3, but that was not my point. Anyways, did the above code work?

Comment: which jars of hibernate 4 is to be used. is it commons-annotations or entire hibernate jars?

Comment: Yes. But you have to check if your project is configured for Hibernate3. Also, that's why I asked if it's an old project. Secondly, if you are getting no error, most likely is that your configuration worked. You can turn on debug logging for hibernate and confirm.

Comment: I donno why i got this error but my project is maven project and i have some unwanted missing jars in my build path.I have removed those jars which are related to itext(pdf).The problem got solved.But i have the question why i am getting unrelated exception.After removal of those jars from build path everything was fine.

Comment: Why are you adding Jars in build-path. Are you not using Maven? If not, then go for maven.

Comment: ya actually i have converted normal project to maven the jars in the build path with location remained asitself